# Create a record of the same type as another

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have a case where I would like to create a new instance of a record based on the type of a record instance that is coming as an argument together with a map of attributes.

```
(defn record-from-instance
  [other attrs]
  ;; Code that creates the new record based on "other"
  )
```

What I have right now is something among the lines:

```
(defn record-from-instance
  [other attrs]
  (let [matched (s/split (subs (str (class other)) 6) #"\.")
        path (s/join "." (pop matched))
        class-name (peek matched)]
    ((resolve (symbol (str path "/" "map->" class-name))) attrs)))
```

Is there any other simpler more idiomatic way to do this that I cannot see?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

To give some more details I am constructing an AST with nodes being records and I am using a zipper to visit and possibly alter / remove parts of the AST. I have an `IZipableTreeNode` protocol

```
(defprotocol IZipableTreeNode
  (branch? [node])
  (children [node])
  (make-node [node children]))
```

Between the different types that implement the `IZipableTreeNode` is `IPersistentMap`

```
  IPersistentMap
  (branch? [node] true)
  (children [node] (seq node))
  (make-node [node children]
    (let [hmap (into {} (filter #(= (count %) 2)) children)]
      (if (record? node)
        (record/from-instance node hmap)
         hmap)))
```

When a visitor say deletes a field from a node (or alters it) the `make-node` gets called with `node` being the record AST node and `children` the new key/value pairs (that may not contain some of the fields in `node`).

Comment: Really this whole question and all your comments on it make me ask, "Why are you using a record at all?" It sounds like you wish records behaved exactly like maps, and you're going to all this work to circumvent their core features.

Comment: @amalloy yes I am using records as nodes of an AST. Do you thing I would be better off using plain maps with a _type_ field instead?

Comment: Added some more details in the description

Comment: @g7s I find the example in your edit to be very confusing. The whole point in using records with protocols would be to use Clojure's polymorphism features, but here you're just implementing the protocol for maps (and all vectors are maps) and then explicitly checking whether it's a record and using the same code for all record types. Could you demonstrate why you are using records at all?

Comment: @SamEstep Because the AST node types are a lot it was very awkward to implement `IZipableTreeNode` for every type separately because the implementation it is exactly the same for every AST node type. So instead I tried to find a way to create a zipper out of _any_ record by extending the `IPersistentMap` protocol. As for the use of records I am using them solely for their type. Think of them as a _typed map_.

Comment: @g7s If the implementation is the same regardless of the type, then you shouldn't be using a protocol; you should just be using regular functions. And yeah, I can't say for sure because I don't know the entirety of what your goal is, but I think that in this case using plain maps with a _type_ field may be a better approach.

Comment: @SamEstep Yeah I guess so too. Using plain maps with a _type_ field starts to sound like a [better idea](https://mkremins.github.io/clojure-ast-ref) for an AST.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought `clojure.core/empty` used to do this. That is, I thought

```
(defrecord Foo [x]) 
(empty (Foo. 1))
```

would return

```
#user.Foo{:x nil}
```

But it certainly doesn't do that now: I'm not sure whether that changed or I misremembered. I can't find a super clean way to do this, but I do at least have something better than your approach. The `user/map->Foo` function you're using is based on the static method generated along with the class, `user.Foo/create`, and it is somewhat classier to invoke that directly instead, through reflection.

```
user> ((fn [r attrs]
         (.invoke (.getMethod (class r) "create" 
                              (into-array [clojure.lang.IPersistentMap]))
                  nil, (into-array Object [attrs])))
       (Foo. 1) {:x 5})
#user.Foo{:x 5}
```

However, it occurs to me now you may not need to do any of this! You started with the preconception that the way to meet your goal of "build a new thing based on a previous thing" was to start from scratch, but why do that? As long as the record being passed into your function doesn't have any "extension" fields added onto it (i.e., those not part of the record definition itself), then you can simply use `clojure.core/into`:

```
(into (Foo. 1) {:x 5}) ;=> #user.Foo{:x 5}
```

Comment: Thanks @amalloy for the answer! I have seen `into` but there is a problem with this. I want the new record instance to have the _exact_ same attributes as the map but `into` merges the map with the record instance. So for example having `(defrecord Bar [x y])`, `(into (Bar. 1) {:y 3})` will return `#user.Bar{:x 1 :y 3}` instead of `#user.Bar{:x nil :y 3}`.

Comment: I mean, what you've written is not *exactly* the same either. `{:x nil :y 3}` is a quite different map from `{:y 3}`. What you're asking for is not possible in the most general case, because maps can have any number of fields (including zero), and records can have a nonzero number of required fields. You have to decide what kind of compromise you're most comfortable with.

Comment: @amalloy It looks like [ClojureScript records implement `empty`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/0bM3nLj18SM) and [Clojure assumes that records implement `empty`](https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1975), so I'd say it's a bug.

Comment: @amalloy you are correct, the maps are not _exactly_ the same. However the `map->` constructors assume all fields are optional that is why are being called with a map in the first place. Given that the requirement of field values is only present in the positional constructor and that the code I am writing assumes that a map gets passed, I can live with this compromise.

Comment: @SamEstep I don't think ClojureScript has `empty` for records. It has `IEmptyableCollection` which is the interface for calling `empty`.

Comment: @g7s Ah, sorry, you're right; I mistook David Nolen's comment about `IEmptyableCollection` to mean that records implemented that, but I was mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

You could also do this:

```
(defn clear [record]
  (reduce (fn [record k]
            (let [without (dissoc record k)]
              (if (= (type record) (type without))
                without
                (assoc record k nil))))
          record
          (keys record)))

(defn map->record [record m]
  (into (clear record) m))
```

Example:

```
(defrecord Foo [x y])

(map->record (map->Foo {:x 1 :y 2 :z 3}) {:y 4})
;;=> #example.core.Foo{:x nil, :y 4}
```

I'm not sure if this would be more efficient or less efficient than @amalloy's reflection approach.

Comment: Nice approach. If the `clear` function is only meant to be called on records then you can safely ditch the type equality checking in the reducer because calling `dissoc` on a record always returns a map. For the code that I am writing though, I do not want `nil` valued fields as it is with your example. It should be non-present instead of `nil`.

Comment: @g7s I do not understand. `dissoc` on a record only returns a map if the key being `dissoc`ed is one of the required keys in the record; that is precisely my reason for using `type`. And in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45443819/create-a-record-of-the-same-type-as-another#comment77851137_45444267) on amalloy's answer, you specifically said that the problem with his `into` approach is that it did not return a record with the entry `:x nil`. Could you please clarify what you mean by your comment here?

Comment: I was wrong `dissoc` indeed returns a map iff the key is in the required keys. Disregard my comment on this. About my comment on amalloy's answer I meant `#user.Bar{:y 3}` (without the `x` field) but realized I made a mistake late and couldn't edit my comment :/

Comment: @g7s You are mistaken there as well; given `(defrecord Bar [x y])`, there is no such object as `#user.Bar{:y 3}`. The closest you can get is indeed `#user.Bar{:x nil :y 3}`.

Comment: Ok it is getting very late here and I guess I need some sleep :P Yes the correct is `#user.Bar{:x nil :y 3}` and your function is giving the same result. Nice!

Comment: @g7s No worries! Let me know if you have further questions in the morning.